# PHP - Что значит хорошо знать язык php

Tags: php

Когда говорят "хорошее знание php" что имеют в виду? Какие технологии php нужно знать (имею в виду MVC, парсинг...), что самое важное. 
И ещё, какие заказы лучше брать или какую работу выполнять для лучшего освоения php. Прошу выразить своё мнение, чем больше тем лучше, каждому лайк!)

Comment: когда говорят хорошие знания языка. имеют в виду хорошие знания непосредственно самого языка. всякие там мвс и парсинги к знаниям языка не относятся. для лучшего освоения пхп нужно взять документацию к нему и изучить ее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У zend (разработчики php) есть сертификация на знание языка.

https://www.zend.com/training/php-certification-exam

По сути там проверяется знание официальной документации и умение работать с языком https://www.php.net/manual/ru/

Стоит сертификация 195 долларов, проходит в специализированном центре. Ты оставляешь телефон, дают бумажку и ручку.

Сдал  - считай что имеешь "хорошее знание php".

Онлайн есть дампы вопросов с экзамена + книжки о том, как готовится.

Даже приложение есть, где можно посмотреть на что это похоже:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twopixeled.zendreviewerfree

Comment: Только в большинстве российских компаний ваш сертификат никому не интересен.